# I am familiar with vim but Can anyone explain a brief working of vim?

Tags: vim

I understand and can write commands in Vim. But i would like to know what happens in the background in Vim. Like whats files are called and how plugins come into play?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very specific and clear. Basically, any configuration is put into a `~/.vimrc` file, like with many other (Unix-based) programs (the native Windows way is more complex). Plugins go into a directory structure in `~/.vim/`. It's basically just putting the files there, and restarting Vim. Many also use *plugin managers* like Pathogen, Vundle, etc.

You'll find all the details under `:help startup`. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.